# RegEx group including escapable characters

Tags: regex, powershell, escaping

I need a regex that will capture all the spaces at the start of a sting, so I can count them. I am using this to convert XML to formatted and color coded HTML with CSS references.

I have this now

```
$regEx = '^( *)'
if ($spaces = [RegEx]::Matches($string, $regEx).value) {
    Write-Host "|$($spaces)|$($spaces.Length)|"
}
```

and it works for a simple string such as

```
$string = '  Some text'
```

But it fails for a more realistic string such as

```
$string = '  <source assetRepository="AWS">\\Server\Assets\Revit\2021'
```

The issue of course being the presence of characters that need to be escaped. But I can't use
[regex]::Escape($regEx), because I need those first special characters. Is there a way to create a character set that includes all escaped characters, that I can put after my spaces group? Or is it all all, nothing or only discretely escaped characters?

Comment: I basically know nothing about PowerShell but why would you need to escape anything? All languages and regex implementations I'm familiar with should treat that regex as...well, a regex. The character sequence there is correct. The string should also have no issues because the string *value* would not really have any escaping in itself - normally a `\n` in a *literal* is transformed as a newline in the string *value*, so if a string is accepted as valid, then no further need to escape anything - the regex is working on the contents of it.

Comment: @vlaz, to be honest I am not sure. I just know that when there are escapable characters in the string, the entire Regex fails, and when there aren't, it succeeds. So I assumed it was a RegEx thing specifically. But I tried it on https://regex101.com and it works for both strings. So now I think it must be a PowerShell specific issue. Arg.

Comment: If that really is the problem, then must be PS. It's definitely not working how I'm used to with other tools but I am not sure why that would be. Hard to guess what the problem might be. Perhaps somebody with PS knowledge might help out and point at the right direction.

Comment: the get the number of leading spaces, compare the length of the original string with the same string that has been trimmed with `.TrimStart(' ')`.

Comment: @lee-dailey I feel like I am in an XKCD panel. https://xkcd.com/1171/
I'll switch gears, but I'll keep the question open since I would still like to know why a RegEx that tests good at regex101.com fails in PowerShell.

Comment: What is the actual problem? The provided code in the example works for me unless a space in the string is not an actual space but is some other white space character like tab. Then `^\s*` works without issues.

Comment: By default, modifiers `g` and `m` are turned on at regex101.com. This means `^\s*` could match multiple lines there. In PowerShell, multi-line mode is not on by default. For the same behavior, you'd use `(?m)^\s*` in PowerShell.

Comment: My issue is when I get formatted XML back via 'System.Xml.XmlTextwriter' I get RegEx parsing errors. Even with your examples. It's odd. But the length and trim approach works for my needs.

Comment: Also, still getting the same errors after addressing the multiple line mode. Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: If you do not provide any additional feedback, your question can easily be closed. Do you want to remove it yourself? I will remove my answer then.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Your solution did not fix it. I still get the same two errors.

Comment: Good, so what are the errors? How to repro them? I can't after using my regex.

Comment: You can't have *"RegEx parsing errors"* with my regexps, they are all correct, and match the whitespace in your sample strings.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Are you working in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Since the first char in your second string is a tab, `\x09`, you can use

```
$regEx = '^[ \t]*'
```

This regex matches any zero or more (`*`) spaces or tabs.

If you plan to match any whitespace at the start of a string, use

```
$regEx = '^\s*'
```

Or, if you do not want to match line break chars, use

```
$regEx = '^[\p{Zs}\t]*'
```

since `[\p{Zs}\t]` matches any horizontal whitespaces.